# Use foreach of array_count_values()

Tags: foreach, key

I would like to do a foreach with a array_count_values() so i need to fecth a column but in th same time fetch all the table user

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT u.username
FROM user u
INNER JOIN chat t ON
    (t.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Ok so I get the username of the key of the foreach but in this key i woulld like to improve it for example to use the key variable as : $key['username'] and more..

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: yes possible. What you have tried?

Comment: I've tried : $variable = array_count_values($array);

Comment: add your php codes and the foreach loop